# Merging different CSVs and labeling column name as their file name

Tags: r

I have different csv files with single-column data. I want to merge them and add a column name as the file name. So far, I have column bind data but unable to add column names.

```
df <- list.files(path='C:/Users/Desktop/Standardized') %>% lapply(read_csv) %>% 
bind_cols()
```

Comment: Note that your code works only if the active working directory folder (i.e. `getwd()`) is "Standardized", unles you use `list.files(,... full.names=TRUE)`

Comment: just change the `lapply` call to this: `lapply(\(x) read_csv(x, col_names = x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possilbe way:

```
path <- 'C:/Users/Desktop/Standardized'
files <- list.files(path)
df <- lapply(file.path(path, files), read_csv) %>% bind_cols() %>% setNames(files)
```